# How to restore kde plasma desktop

Tags: kde, kde4, plasma

I was tried chrome remote desktop app with a friend. He has a Mac. By mistake he clicked cmd + s, I do not know if that is super + s combination, the thing is it killed all my kde plasma widgets.

Is there a short way to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the solution. Was really simple, it creates a new activity. It is as simple as:

1. go to activities
2. change back to the old one, and
3. stop and delete the new one.